# await a future function to return value till another future is resolved in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am calling multiple future Under a future call.I want to return the value from the  sendAndSyncOrder() function after all future function under it is resolved.I want to call this function on an on tap fuction and want to get the bool value after all future function under it is resolved .Here is my code:

```
`Future<bool> sendAndSyncOrder() async {
    bool returnValue;
    databaseHelper.fetchToSyncOrder().then(
      (value) async {
        print('resolved');
        if (!value.length.isNaN) {
          unSyncOrd = value.length.toString();
          value.forEach(
            (element) async {
              await sendOrderToServer(
                element.products,
                element.amount,
                element.dateTime,
                element.id,
                element.cusId,
              ).then(
                (val) {
                  print(val);
                  print('from sync');
                  if (!val) {
                    returnValue = val;
                  }
                  if (val) {
                    databaseHelper.updateOrder(
                      OrderItem(
                        id: element.id,
                        cusId: element.cusId,
                        amount: element.amount,
                        products: element.products,
                        dateTime: element.dateTime,
                        syncStatus: val,
                      ),
                    );
                    notifyListeners();
                  }
                },
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
    print('from sendAndSyncOrder');
    return returnValue;
  }`
```

Comment: Why are you both `await`ing and using `.then`?

Comment: I was just receiving the value on await to check,I know it redundant I will remove it.

Comment: It's not really redundant in your case, but it could be simplified easily. What is your intended result and how was your code not already achieving this?

Comment: I want to return the value from this function when all the future calls inside this function is resolved.U can see I am setting the return value from another future calls result.But before I can set the value.this function is returning a NULL value to it,s caller.I need some way to make her w8 to return value after I can set it's return value where the value is coming from another future call

Comment: Maybe you can use `Future.wait`, take a look at this [documentation](https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-advanced-futures-api/#code-classlanguage-textfuturewaitcode).

Comment: @JRamos29 `Future.wait` does not help here.

Comment: @TanvirArafat You `return` the `.then` and your `return` inside the `.then` callback as well. There are many examples of this online. Adding `await` as you had it in you original post should have been fine, but is messy. When you're combining `await` and `.then` it usually means there is a better way you could be doing it.

Comment: I have tried to return the value on then call back but it dosen't work

Comment: When the 1st future is resolved it calls the then call back,it dosen't w8 for the other futures inside it

Comment: You have to do that for *every* nested `.then` call. This is why `await` leads to cleaner code.